# How do I iterate through a list containing objects? c#

Tags: c#, list, object, foreach

I created a list that stores objects from another class. The objects stored in my list each have a name and an integer. I want to know if I can iterate through my list and display the name of each object. If I change the type of i to VAR or Dynamic it says its out of range.

```
    public List<InventoryHandling> Inventory = new List<InventoryHandling>();

    public void inventorySelect()
    {
        Inventory[0] = new InventoryHandling("Potion", 4);

        foreach(int i in Inventory)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Inventory[i].Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are no `int` in `inventory`. Either iterate by for and index or by foreach and items

Comment: `Inventory[0] = new InventoryHandling("Potion", 4);` this only works if there already is an item in the list, that you can replace. Did you maybe want to `.Add()` to the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start, this line is wrong:

```
Inventory[0] = new InventoryHandling("Potion", 4);
```

The problem is the `[0]` index refers to the first item in the list, but (presumably) at this point the list doesn't have **any** space yet. The position at index `[0]` *doesn't exist*, and C# does not allow you to append to a list by assigning to the next index. Instead, when you want to add new items to a list, you should call it's `.Add()` method:

```
Inventory.Add(new InventoryHandling("Potion", 4));
```

---

Now we have a list with some content, we can talk about how to iterate it. And just like appending, you **don't use indexes** with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(InventoryHandling ih in Inventory)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ih.Name);
}
```

If you really want to use indexes, you can do it with a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Inventory.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Inventory[i].Name);
}
```

Comment: Curious why this was downvoted.